# sed removing everything until and including the first period if there's more than one period on that line and do this for the whole file

Tags: awk, sed

`sed` removing everything until and including the first period if there is more than one period on that line and do this for the whole file.

Before sed:

```
akamai.com
cdnjs.cloudflare.com
com.cdn.cloudflare.net
```

After sed:

```
akamai.com
cloudflare.com
cdn.cloudflare.net
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$ sed '/\..*\./s/^[^.]*\.//' file
akamai.com
cloudflare.com
cdn.cloudflare.net
```

The `sed` script first matches lines that contain at least two dots using the regular expression `\..*\.` (could also have been written `[.].*[.]`).  For lines matching this, a substitution that removes everything up to and including the first dot is performed.

Using `awk`, being somewhat long-winded in comparison to the above:

```
$ awk -F '.' -vOFS='.' 'NF > 2 { n=split($0, a); $0=""; for (i=2;i<=n;++i) $(NF+1)=a[i] } 1' file
akamai.com
cloudflare.com
cdn.cloudflare.net
```

Here, whenever there are more than two dot-delimited fields, we split the current line on dots, and then re-create the current record from that, skipping the first field.  The trailing `1` at the end causes every line (modified or not) to be printed.

Shorter `awk` in the same fashion as the `sed` solution:

```
$ awk -F '.' 'NF > 2 { sub("^[^.]*\.", "") } 1' file
akamai.com
cloudflare.com
cdn.cloudflare.net
```

Comment: It is possible to use only one regex in sed: `sed '/\.\([^.]*\.\)/s//\1/' infile` and the awk could be a lot smaller: `awk '$0~re{sub(/^[^.]*\./,"")}1' re='^[^.]*\\.([^.]*\\.)' infile`

Comment: Grep gets a bit complex: `grep -P '^(?=[^.]*\.[^.]*\.)[^.]*\.\K.*|.*' infile`

Answer (score 1):

You could approach this using the following methods:

```
perl -lpe '$_ = $1 if /\.(.*\..*)/' input-file.txt
```

wherein, we rely on a `regex` that zeroes in on a dot `.` character that can see another dot to it's right. Then whatever is to the right is captured and made available in `$1` and stuffed inside the current line. The `-p` option to `Perl` then takes this to the `stdout` as well as the one that didn't match as well.

---

```
perl -F\\. -pale '$_ = join ".", splice @F, 1 if @F > 2' input.txt
```

- Input file is read line-by-line via the `-p` option and autoprint is also turned on via this option as well.
- Each record is split on the dot `.` and the individual fields stored in the array `@F` indexed starting from `0` via the `-a` option.
- `-l` option makes `RS = ORS = "\n"`
- Only when we have more than 2 elements in the array `@F`, meaning there were atleast 2 dots in the current record, we select such a record for modifications.
- For such a record, the `splice @F, 1` function strips away elements 2nd onwards and presents them to the `join` function which then joins them using the dot character, this then is stuffed inside the `$_` , aka, current record.
- The `-p` option then takes this modified current record to the stdout. The one that didnot modify is anyway taken silently to the stdout.

---

Using `GNU sed` we can also do the task without taking recourse of capturing parens:

```
sed -e 
    s/\./\n/2;T
    y/\n./.\n/
    s/\n/./2g
    s/.*\n//
' input.file
```

---

Output:

```
akamai.com
cloudflare.com
cdn.cloudflare.net
```